# Where do I find the following aqua components?

Tags: qiskit

```py
from qiskit.aqua import QuantumInstance
from qiskit.aqua.components.optimizers import COBYLA
from qiskit.aqua.components.variational_forms import RY
from qiskit.aqua.algorithms import VQE
```

I am unable to implement it in my code and cannot figure out if the following libraries have been shifted to `qiskit-terra` or somewhere else?

Answer (score 1):

The Qiskit Aqua support [finished on December 2021 after being deprecated on April 2021](https://github.com/qiskit-community/qiskit-aqua?tab=readme-ov-file#qiskit-aqua-now-deprecated).

For the objects you are referring in your post, currently (March 2024) the situation is:

- `qiskit.aqua.QuantumInstance` was replaced by primitives. See migration guide [here](https://qisk.it/algo_migration)
- `qiskit.aqua.components.optimizers.COBYLA` is now `qiskit_algorithms.optimizers.COBYLA` ([docs](https://qiskit-community.github.io/qiskit-algorithms/stubs/qiskit_algorithms.optimizers.COBYLA.html))
- `qiskit.aqua.components.variational_forms.RY` has no direct replacement
- `qiskit.aqua.algorithms.VQE` is now in `qiskit_algorithms.VQE` ([docs](https://qiskit-community.github.io/qiskit-algorithms/stubs/qiskit_algorithms.VQE.html))

The alternative is to have an environment with old version of `qiskit-aqua` and its dependencies at April 2021 and a Python 3.8. Something like this:

```
qiskit-terra==0.18.0
qiskit-ignis==0.6.0
scipy==1.5
sympy==1.3
numpy==1.17
psutil==5
scikit-learn==0.20
dlx==1.0.4
docplex==2.21.207
fastdtw==0.3.4
setuptools==40.1.0
h5py==3.4
pandas==1.3
quandl==3.6
yfinance==0.1.62
retworkx==0.8.0
```